# how to show the table data into table using ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

This is My response data from Api. By using ng-repeat how to show data into the table. 
response contains array of arrays.
itemsList is My response data  name.

```
[Array[1], Array[0]]
0:Array[1]
0:Resource
$$hashKey:"object:22"
__v:0
_id:"5712254566dfa48c16d481d5"
bprice:100
createdat:"2016-04-16T11:43:01.471
modifiedat:"2016-04-16T11:43:01.471Z"
notifyqty:10
prodcutcategory:"sport shoe"
productcode:"439971"
productname:"zxcvb"
productnote:"zdc"
productqty:60
size:8
sprice:200
__proto__:Object
$$hashKey:
"object:20"
$promise:Promise
$resolved:true
length:1
__proto__:Array[0]
1:Array[1]
0:Resource
$$hashKey:"object:26"
__v:0
_id:"5712257366dfa48c16d481d6"
bprice:100
createdat:
"2016-04-16T11:43:47.462Z"
modifiedat:"2016-04-16T11:43:47.463Z"
notifyqty:10
prodcutcategory:"Sandal"
productcode:"590893"
productname:"bata"
productnote:"rough"
productqty:50
size:7
sprice:150
__proto__:
Object
$$hashKey:"object:24"
$promise:Promise
$resolved:true
length:1
__proto__:Array[0]
length:2
__proto__:Array[0]
```

this is my Table repetition in html

```
 <tr ng-repeat="list in itemsList">
                          <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
                          <td>{{list.productname}}</td>
                          <td>{{list.productquantity}}</td>
                          <td>{{list.sprice}}</td>
                          <td>{{list.sprice*list.productquantity}}</td>
                         <td><button type="button" class="fa fa-trash btn   btn-danger" ng-click="remove($index,list._id)"></button></td>

                      </tr>
```

When i Click on button it send the barcode as ng-model from input 
i got the response from services.
and finally the response push into itemsList every time each new entry of barcode

```
 $scope.getOrder=function(barcode){
    $scope.orderlist=GetproductBarcodeService.getAllCartofproducts(barcode);
    $scope.itemsList.push($scope.orderlist)
    console.log($scope.itemsList)
 }
```

please tell me how to repeat this.

Comment: You have already added code to repeat `itemsList`. What problem/error are you facing to repeat it?

Comment: i am not getting data in the table.it shows empty

Comment: show some controller code..

Comment: ok. i change the code check once

Comment: Can you tell , " $scope.orderlist " data & " $scope.itemsList " data ?

Comment: $scope.orderlist is resonse from services then i push those response to the $scope,itemsList from each barcode(ng-model)

Answer (score 0):

Try this controller code may be help you

```
//Create itemsList array 
    $scope.itemsList = [];

$scope.getOrder = function(){
// Use example result 
        $scope.orderlist = { id : '312312',data : 'wel come'};
        console.log($scope.orderlist);
        $scope.itemsList.push($scope.orderlist);
        console.log($scope.itemsList);
    }
```

Try this and see you console log out put